# OSError(28, 'No space left on device') error in Snowflake while loading big file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting error  OSError(28, 'No space left on device') while copying 15 GB zip file into snowflake AWS, via snowsql. Can someone help me to understand this error and how to avoid it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJNvC.png)

My VM has multiple disk, except root all other mapped drive have minimum 210 GB of storage available. Tried to set export TEMPDIR=/backups2 but that didn't worked. Any suggestions

Comment: How much free space is on your hard drive? SnowSQL is going to encrypt and compress the file, so it requires free space to do that.

Comment: Thanks @GregPavlik for clarifying my doubts regarding error. I have updated my post, can you help me to identify which drive it is using for encryption, file is already compressed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to the file size you can use with the PUT command. The recommendation is to split the file into small data files ranging in size from roughly 100 to 250 MB compressed and upload them in parallel.

Check the document here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html